# How to copy Visual studio 2010 projects to use in other system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, project

I have developed a website using Visual studio 2010. Now one of my friend needs that website/project to copy in his system for further development. But whenever i copy from default VS project folder, it is not running in other system( Installed same version of Visual studio). I have done same with VS 2008 and it was working fine.

Comment: The most probable reason is, that you have references pointing to a local path on your system. Side note: Did you already consider sharing your code via an online repository like Team Foundation Server/Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Project does not exist. and size is like 3kb.

Comment: I have not done any sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps :

image 1:

[image]

1. Copy the entire project folder  (must Copy the entire project )
2. Open Visual Studio in Admin Mode
3. Open the solution file   (you can see in the image 1 -**project file**)
4. **Re-Build** the Solution

How to copy from root folder of project :

Just right click the project and find options.

[image]

**Note** : Visual Studio 10 - Framework = 4.5 ,previous versions will not have the same framework so tools and references should be taken care of.They will not load if framework is different.

Comment: But in default folder, only .sln file is there with size around 2kb

Comment: Thats what i am telling i have only one file named 'website7.sln'. whenever i open that file it automatically goes to visual studio and opens solution.

Comment: i assume you are not copying all the files ..thatsy its not showing the entire files

Comment: The option which you are suggesting, it was present in VS 2008. but currently i am using VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

Probably the full path to the solution folder should be the same on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to use tools like Github.
These help to maintain a version of the files and all the organizations use some kind of version-ing system 
https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2014/08/01/what-github-and-how-can-it-benefit-your-development-team

So following this practice will help you later when you will start developing professionally

and the tool is free :)